# How to get jabber.el to download all message history?

Tags: jabber

I'm using jabber.el and it's working great. I'm trying to find out if there's a way to have jabber download my recent chat history when initiating a chat with someone. It seems like my history is cached for conversations that occur while I'm online, but messages I missed while offline are not downloaded.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: If messages are sent while you are offline, and the messages haven't been seen by any other client before, then the server should send them to jabber.el at connection time. What server are you connecting to?

Comment: BTW, does running `M-x jabber-chat-display-more-backlog` in a chat buffer help?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with XMPP but from what I have read and seen, it looks like HipChat (I'm assuming you're using hipchat) doesn't follow the XMPP standard for offline messages, as such getting offline messages seems to only be supported on their official clients. I could be wrong, but if offline message support was available, `jabber-get-disco-info` would not yield a "Feature not implemented" error. Basically if you can't discover offline support, then it's definitely not there. (I could be wrong)

Comment: @legoscia that does help in an individual chat. groupchats seem not to like that command.

Comment: @JordonBiondo bummer. :(

Comment: Are you using hipchat rooms? It's strange because I can't get message history for individual message on hipchat, but I get the history of rooms automatically.

Comment: @JordonBiondo yeah, that's the same behavior I get as well. Individual messages I can't download but the room history works just fine.